# Can I control the size and/or number of shared files when exporting tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Generally if we have a nested table in BQ, while exporting it to GCS, it'll create multiple chunks.

I have one table which is 500GB in size. I did an export then it creates around 5000 files and each files are in around 70mb.

**How can I force a custom chunk size like 1gb or number of files to split in BQ export?**

Comment: is the table partitioned? clustered? how did you request the export?

Comment: Maybe a Googler will correct me, but I don't believe it's possible to control the size and number of shards. At least, I've never seen anything in the API. Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334241/exporting-data-to-gcs-from-bigquery-split-file-size-control

Comment: @FelipeHoffa its a normal table(actually its a google analytics dataset), no partitions. I used BQ command line to export the data.

Comment: I think Google Analytics exports to multiple tables - hence you might be seeing a different file for each day of data?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I want to export each day's data. every day I need to export current day's data(doesn't matter the time of the day)